# Is there a way to solve NoSuchMethodError originating from indexedStack when using a list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The indexedStack I use to show a series of pictures one after the other is the origination of a noSuchMethod error. I am trying to build the stack using a list in my firebase like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chNN6.png)

The relevant code that causes the error is here; channelData is defined as channelData =
Map<String, dynamic>.from(widget.channelSnapshot.data() as Map); where "posts" is the list that holds the sublists with the timestamps and links.

```
                  IndexedStack(
                    index: index,
                    children: channelData["posts"]
                        .toList()((doc) {
                          precacheImage(
                              NetworkImage(doc["postPicUrl"]), context);
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 280,
                                height: 150,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(doc["postPicUrl"]),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                )),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                  )
```

The error code is here:

```
  Dynamic call of object has no instance method 'call'.
  Receiver: Instance of 'List<dynamic>'
  Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Padding']
  The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Builder
```

I know that the issue is probably how I'm presenting the list to the indexedStack. The code was working when I was doing the same thing with snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) as the children of the indexedStack instead of channelData[posts]. I know that indexedstack is the source of the issue because when it is removed the page loads fine, including the widgets also dependent on data from that list. I have tried changing the location of the .toList(); changing which widget is shown first, etc, but there really aren't any similar issues on the internet. Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

You're missing the `.map()` statement before the `((doc) {...}).toList()` callback.

From your current code, you're attempting to call a method on the List which is why the error message says:

```
Dynamic call of object has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'List<dynamic>'
```

### Solution:

Map the List by calling `.map()` on the list and passing it the callback.

Change block of code:

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: index,
  children: channelData["posts"]
    .toList()((doc) {
      ...                          
    }).toList(),
)
```

to this:

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: index,
  children: channelData["posts"]
    .toList().map<Widget>((doc) {
      ...                          
    }).toList(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was hoping it would be something like this! the only thing I needed to do in addition to this was to put <widget> after map, as that's the type needed by indexedstack